# HTML sends x y POST data with no inputs - how is this possible?

Tags: http, curl

I am trying to logging using php's curl.

I am using LiveHTTPHeaders to see what headers are sent.

When I login through form it sends

```
action=autorize&login=myname&pass=mypass&x=14&y=10
```

I can see `action`, `login`, `pass` `<inputs>`.
The problem is - there are no `x` and `y` inputs. And they are random all the time. I searched all html, but there are definitely no any x, y or their numbers.

How is that possible at all?

Comment: are you using <input type="image"...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The x and y inputs are from an image input.  From W3C:

> An INPUT element with 'TYPE=IMAGE'
>   specifies an image resource to
>   display, and allows input of two form
>   fields: the x and y coordinate of a
>   pixel chosen from the image. The names
>   of the fields are the name of the
>   field with '.x' and '.y' appended.
>   'TYPE=IMAGE' implies 'TYPE=SUBMIT'
>   processing; that is, when a pixel is
>   chosen, the form as a whole is
>   submitted.

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.1.2.5

Comment: I thought about something like this, even tried to google it, but 'x' and 'y' are hard to search. Didn't noticed that it was image.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an image as button. those are the coordinates clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from input type="image" it auto submits the x and y coordinates that you have clicked on the submit button.